# Discord.py doesn't play audio

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, audio-player

Basically I made a bot that just simply plays music, I made a command that plays the song so you do `?play [url of song]` and it will play, now I'm working on a ?search command that you can enter the keyword and it will play the song, after alot of errors I got it to find the songs when you typed them. But it doesn't stream the sound over the audio (but it does though when you use the ?play command) This is my code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import youtube_dl
import requests

class music(commands.Cog):
  def __init__(self, client):
    self.client = client
  

  @commands.command()
  async def join(self,ctx):
    if ctx.author.voice is None:
      await ctx.send("Join a voice channel dumb fuck")
    voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    if ctx.voice_client is None:
      await voice_channel.connect()
    else:
      await ctx.voice_client.move_to(voice_channel)
  
  @commands.command()
  async def disconnect(self,ctx):
    await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()
  
  @commands.command()
  async def play(self,ctx,url):
    ctx.voice_client.stop()
    FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}
    YDL_OPTIONS = {'format':"bestaudio"}
    vc = ctx.voice_client

    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
      info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
      url2 = info['formats'][0]['url']
      source = await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(url2, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS)
      vc.play(source)
  
  @commands.command()
  async def search(self, ctx, arg):
    ctx.voice_client.stop()
    try:
      requests.get("" + str(arg))
    except: arg = " " + str(arg)
    else: arg = "" + str(arg)
    YDL_OPTIONS = {'format':"bestaudio"}
    vc = ctx.voice_client
    FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
      info = ydl.extract_info(f"ytsearch:{arg}", download=False)['entries'][0]
      url2 = info['formats'][0]['url']
      return {'source': info['formats'][0]['url'], 'title': info['title']}
      source = await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(url2, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS)
      vc.play(source)

  
  @commands.command()
  async def pause(self,ctx):
    await ctx.voice_client.pause()
    await ctx.send("PAUSED")
  
  @commands.command()
  async def resume(self,ctx):
    await ctx.voice_client.resume()
    await ctx.send("RESUMED")

def setup(client):
  client.add_cog(music(client))
```

The console doesn't give any errors it just says this:

```
[download] Downloading playlist:  superidol
[youtube:search] query " superidol": Downloading page 1
[youtube:search] playlist  superidol: Downloading 1 videos
[download] Downloading video 1 of 1
[youtube] chY9p-XLHHk: Downloading webpage
[download] Finished downloading playlist:  superidol
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know the answer but from the things you said and what the console sent, I think it downloaded the webpage, not the video.

If that the case there's no way of playing a webpage so this can be the issue.

*PS: I sent an answer, not a comment since I dont have enough reputation.*

Comment: I think you were right I ended up removing the ```return {'source': video['formats'][0]['url'], 'title': video['title']}``` cuz i think that formatted the webpage or something instead of the actual video and replaced it with other code. It works now thanks!

Comment: @vixitu can you share the code that you used for the fix. I have the same issue :)